# How to let different processes use different network interfaces?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm on the client side. There're multiple network interfaces. How can I let different processes use different network interfaces to communicate? Since I want to connect to the same server, routing seems not working here. Also, `connect()` doesn't have arguments to specify local address or interface as `bind()` does.

Comment: Why do you think you need them to use different interfaces to the the same server? What makes you think 'routing isn't working here'? Why should connect() allow you to specify a local address when bind() already does that? What's the question?

Comment: I want to communicate with the same server via multiple network interfaces to utilize all bandwidth on the client.

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to increase bandwidth to the server by using multiple network interfaces in parallel, then that's probably not something you can (or should) do at the application level.  Instead, you should study up on [Link Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) and then configure your computer and networking stack to use that.  Once that is working properly, you will get the parallelization-speedup you want automatically, without the client application having to do anything special to enable it.

Answer (score 4):

> "The bind() system call is frequently misunderstood. It is used to
>   bind to a particular IP address. Only packets destined to that IP
>   address will be received, and any transmitted packets will carry that
>   IP address as their source. bind() does not control anything about the
>   routing of transmitted packets. So for example, if you bound to the IP
>   address of eth0 but you send a packet to a destination where the
>   kernel's best route goes out eth1, it will happily send the packet out
>   eth1 with the source IP address of eth0. This is perfectly valid for
>   TCP/IP, where packets can traverse unrelated networks on their way to
>   the destination."

More info e.g. [here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/10/code-snippet-sobindtodevice.html).

That's why you probably misunderstand bind() call.

The appropriate way to bind to physical topology (to some specific interface) is to use `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option. This is done by `setsockopt()` call.

Answer (score 2):

`Source Policy Routing` might be helpful.

Try the following steps:

- Use `iptables` to give packets from different process with different marks.
- Use `iproute2` to route packets with different marks to different table.
- In different table, set the default route to different uplink.

The whole process require certain amount of understanding about linux networking.

Here is an example shows how to route all traffic for a user through one specific uplink: http://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/08/28/making-all-network-traffic-for-a-linux-user-use-a-specific-network-interface/

You could try follow similar approach by running different process with different user and route traffic from one user to one uplink.

Also you could let processes communicate with the server with different port and mark the traffic by port.